# Is there an equivalent for coconutBattery (Mac) on the Android?

Tags: applications, battery

My G2 android used to last an entire day without charge for the past year, now it appears that it gets to very low energy at about halfway through the day, is there something like coconutBattery (Mac) for the Android? Not sure if this question belong on SO or somewhere else?

I am essentially looking for original Design Capacity (ie. 6900 mAh) and now the Current capacity (6559 mAh)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the information is available in `Settings -> About Phone -> Status` but you can also use an app from the market called [Battery Info](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.stu.battery&hl=en) (i am sure there are others as well) and it will show you all the information on the battery. This app also has a widget that can display some information too.

[image]

At the time of me writing this it is not possible in the android SDK to get the [raw mAH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511673/read-maximum-battery-charge-mah-on-android) value so you wont find any apps that can display the exact mAH, only how charged the battery is in percent, and what is drained.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Conrad, please see my edit above, I am looking for Original Design capacity and Current Capacity of battery, u know if any apps have that?

Comment: I added to my answer to address your edit.